# iOS Detect dynamic modifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection, runtime

I am using reflection to see a list of classes/methods at runtime.

Is there a way to detect if a class/method/property was added at runtime, using for example one of the ObjC Runtime functions?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1657527-objective_c_runtime